# How can I move legend in Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

By default legend is displaying at the top-right side of the graph. I want to show it just above the graph. I've used the following code:

```
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    x: 600,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 40,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
}
```

But it is not working for me. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 33):

Like this:

```
legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.verticalAlign
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.align

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to place legend above whole graph or just above plot? Is that what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/8Qm5a/

Anyway, if you need to place legend above the title, try to change `marginTop` of chart settings and set `y` settings in title options:

```
    chart: {
        marginTop: 100
    },

    title: {
        text: "test",
        y: 60
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Qm5a/1/